# SonataAdminBundle preload SQL objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

When using SonataAdminBundle, I am trying to visualize the leaf nodes of a database. My tables are A -> B -> C (-> = contains some). The leaf nodes I try to visualize is C.

C has a __toString() which will call B.__toString(), which in turns calls A.__toString().

**The problem:** I end up showing 30 lines and making 700 calls to the database.

Sometimes, I can avoid this problem by adding a filter, so it would make a request with the filter first and would "preload" some objects, but in this case, I can't add a filter as such.

Is there a way to preload my objects beforehand? The answer would probably contain 2 parts:

- Where in Sonata should I do this?
- What code should I execute to preload a hierarchy of objects which would minimize the amount of calls to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override method `createQuery` where you can place your custom joins.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;

class CarAdmin extends Admin
{
    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);
        $query->leftJoin($query->getRootAlias . '.Model', 'mo');
        $query->leftJoin('mo.Make', 'ma');

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Remember that, `createQuery` method returns Sonata ProxyQuery object, not Doctrine Query. So you should operate on query returned by `Admin::createQuery`.

Comment: However, the filter is having the same problem. Where should I run my JOIN to fetch the filter properties properly?